# There is Option to read data from socket without the server close the socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I created application in android studio and server in python and I want to connect the client to my server with one socket per client so that I don't need to close the socket and I could send data from the server to any connected client I want.

My server is multi-threaded and it working only if I'm closing every socket after sending data back.

At my java app I created class that contain socket object and methods to contact with the server and I think that my problem is at this method:

```
private static  String getMessageFromServer() throws IOException {
        in = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        bf = new BufferedReader(in);

        return bf.readLine();
    }
```

As you can see this method reads data from the server and the problem is that it keep reading data until the server close the socket, so I'm asking if there is any option to read data from server and stop the reading after I already got the data and without the server closes the socket?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Your client tries to read a line with .readLine(). So you should let the server send lines. A line is just a text string that ends with the newline character \n.

Comment: `"Hello client how are you?\n"`.

Comment: Thank you!! , I changed my server that at the end of the data I'm adding "\n" and it worked!